# Behat says Firefox Binary not found in path, but it's in path

Tags: windows, firefox, selenium, behat

Trying to run Behat on a new Windows PC. I installed Firefox, and added the location to my path, and restarted the terminal.

I confirmed it's in the system path by:

1. If I do `echo %path%`, the variable ends in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox;` which is the correct location.
2. `where firefox` outputs `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`
3. typing just `firefox` into the console launches the browser.

I have selenium running, and when I try to launch the behat test, I get this error.

```
[WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError]

Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: VISTA

Build info: version: '2.38.0', revision: 'bd32d4e', time: '2013-12-05 16:15:38'

System info: host: 'Jessica-DELL', ip: '192.168.1.85', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

My behat config file (which works on other PCs) is as follows.

```
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
      mink_driver: true
      kernel:
        env: test
        debug: true
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      default_session: symfony2
      javascript_session: selenium2
      goutte:    ~
      selenium2:
        capabilities: { "browser": "firefox", browserName: "firefox", "version": "29" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the path needs to point to the .exe, not just the folder.  Try setting the path variable to the full filepath:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe